# Find file by magic pattern maching

Tags: find, file-command

There is a bash command file(1) which outputs a file's contents type according to the matching pattern definitions in the /etc/magic and /usr/share/misc/magic.

Is there a way to use these pattern definition "magic" files as a test for the "find" command?

For example, there are some text files and "PalmOS application" files

```
file -b palmapp
PalmOS application

file -b readme.txt
ASCII text
```

I need some way to find the files which match "PalmOS application" rather than "ASCII text", for example this is an ideal command:

```
find . -magic "PalmOS*"
```

Is there any idea to write a single-line bash command making for each file this test?

Answer (score 4):

Something along the lines of:

`find . -print -exec file {} \; | grep "PalmOS"`

To tidy up the output pipe through awk as well by adding:

`| awk '{print substr($1,2,length($1)-2)}'`

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in feature of `find` to analyze the file content, but you can make it invoke `file`. Using the shell to combine multiple task-specific programs (`find` to traverse directory trees, `file` to analyze file content) is the Unix way of doing things.

You want to act on files for which the output of the command `file -b -- "$filename"` contains the string `PalmOS application`. That can be tested with the shell script

```
case "$(file -b -- "$filename")" in *"PalmOS application"*) true;; *) false;; esac
```

You can use this script in a `find` command like this:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'case "$(file -b "$0")" in *"PalmOS application"*) true;; *) false;; esac' {} \; -print
```

Replace `-print` by the action you want to take (which can be another `-exec …`). This second action is only executed if the previous action is true, which is when the shell command returns 0 (i.e. true).

Alternatively, in zsh, you can let the shell do the directory traversal with the [`**` glob](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing). The `.` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) restricts the matches to regular files (like `-type f` for `find`).

```
for x in **/*(.); do
  [[ $(file -b -- $x) = *"PalmOS application"* ]] || continue
  …
done
```

In bash ≥4.3, you can use `**` for recursive globbing, but you need to enable the `globstar` option first. In bash 4.0–4.2, `globstar` is already available, but beware that `**` traverses symbolic links to directories. In ksh93, use `set -o globstar` instead of `shopt -s globstar`.

```
shopt -s globstar
for x in **/*; do
  [[ -f $x ]] || continue
  [[ $(file -b -- "$x") = *"PalmOS application"* ]] || continue
  …
done
```

If your file names don't contain whitespace or any of `:\"'` then an alternate method is to run `file` on the file names and parse the output.

```
find -type f |
xargs file |
sed -n 's/:.*PalmOS application.*//p' |
xargs somecommand
```

If your file names contain whitespace but no newlines or colons then you can use the shell to do the parsing.

```
find -type f |
while IFS=: read -r filename type; do
  case "$type" in
    *"PalmOS application"*)
      …;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use `find`, but setting `pattern` and `directory` will produce the results your question asks for:

```
pattern="PalmOS application"
directory=.

for f in $directory/*; do
    if [[ $(file -b $f) == "$pattern" ]]; then
        echo $f; 
    fi; 
done
```